# Screen Capture Specific Areas of Screen for OCR

Tags: screen, ocr, capture, rectangles

Does anyone know of any libraries or ideas how to achieve screen captures which can then be used with OCR?

What I need is to be able to record 3 or 4 rectangles on the screen (ignoring outside these areas) which can then be used to recognise the text which will hopefully appear inside these areas at some point on time.

Ideally vb.net / c#.net or similar would be useful...

Does anyone have any experience with this, or could offer some useful advise?

Many thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There is more than likely an easier way to do it.

Comment: I am looking to recognise shapes and text from an image in certain parts of the screen.  Basically there are a number of labels on a machine which is being watched via a camera on a PC.  At various points there will be labels appearing and I want to create some software which will pick these up from the PC.

Comment: That actually sounds like an interesting problem. Unfortunately your question came off as somewhat obscure and uninteresting. I suggest resubmitting your question, framed as more of a machine vision problem, and explain what you are trying to do. Getting the "rectangle" screen capture shouldn't really be the focus of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the coordinates of those rectangles, you can send them along with the image to Tesseract engine for OCR. Tesseract exposes an API method that takes an image and rectangular coordinates.

You can use its .NET wrappers: [tessnet2](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/) for Tess 2.04 and [tesseractdotnet](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/) for Tess 3.01.